# Backbone: All models in collection are the same

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

When new model is added to the collection, values of all attributes of all previous models are set to the values of the new model.

Here is full source code: https://github.com/dirty-hippie/chocolate/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts

The flow:

1) in the first section user choose form of the sweetie - a bar, a candy or a figure. Code is in views/form.coffee

```
class App.Views.Form extends Backbone.View

  template: HandlebarsTemplates['form']
  tagName: 'label',
  className: 'product control-as-image'
  events:
    'click img': 'selectForm'

  render: -> 
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    @el.setAttribute('for', "form-" +@model.get('id'))    
    @

  selectForm: ->
    App.Vent.trigger "form:select", {name: @model.get('name'), price: @model.get('price')}
```

2) in the next section user choose ingredients: recommended (a radiobox) or individual (checkboxes, up to three). Code is in views/ingredient.coffee

```
class App.Views.Ingredient extends Backbone.View

  template: HandlebarsTemplates['ingredient']
  tagName: 'label',
  className: 'product control-as-image'
  attributes:
    "data-component" : "ingredient"
   events:
    'click img': 'selectIngredient'

  render: ->   
     #handlebar сompotability
    if @model.get('kind') == 'recipe'
      @model.set('isRecipe', true)
    else
      @model.set('isRecipe', false)

    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    @el.setAttribute('for', "ingredient-" + @model.get('id'))    
    @

  dataForOrder: ->    
    name: @model.get('name')    

  selectIngredient: (event) ->         
    if @model.get('kind') == 'recipe'
      App.Vent.trigger "ingredient:set", @dataForOrder()
    else #dealing with compound ingredients, up to three      
      unless @el.childNodes[1].checked #state before the click
        App.Vent.trigger "ingredient:push", @dataForOrder() #checked
      else
        App.Vent.trigger "ingredient:pop", @dataForOrder() #unchecked
```

3) press ad to the basket. Code is in views/line_item.coffee
    class App.Views.LineItem extends Backbone.View

```
  template: HandlebarsTemplates['line_item']

  events: 
    'click #send-to-basket' : 'sendToBasket'
  initialize: ->
    @listenTo App.Vent, 'form:select', @setForm
    @listenTo App.Vent, 'ingredient:set', @setIngredient
    @listenTo App.Vent, 'ingredient:push', @pushIngredient
    @listenTo App.Vent, 'ingredient:pop', @popIngredient

    @template = HandlebarsTemplates['order_item'] if @model.get('inBasket')

  render: -> 
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    @

  setForm: (form) ->
    @model.set('form', form)    

  setIngredient: (ingredient) ->
    @model.set('ingredients', [ingredient])

  pushIngredient: (ingredient) ->    
    ingredients = @model.get('ingredients')
    if ingredients.length < 3
      ingredients = [] if ingredients[0] and ingredients[0].isRecipe #reset
      ingredients.push(ingredient)
      @model.set 'ingredients', ingredients

  popIngredient: (removedIngredient) ->
    ingredients = @model.get('ingredients')    
    _.remove ingredients, (ingredient) ->
      ingredient.name is removedIngredient.name
    @model.set 'ingredients', ingredients

  sendToBasket: ->
    if @model.get('form') isnt null and @model.get('ingredients').length > 0
      App.Vent.trigger "order:add", {form: @model.get('form'), ingredients:     @model.get('ingredients')}     
    else          
      $.pnotify
        title: 'Выберите форму и начинку'
```

4) when sweetie is added to the basket somehow all previous sweeties become identical to new one. Code is in views/order.coffee

```
class App.Views.Order extends Backbone.View

 renderItem: (model) ->
   model.set('inBasket', true)
   v = new App.Views.LineItem({model: model})    
   @$el.find("#line-items").append(v.render().el)


  addItem: (item) ->        
    @collection.add new App.Models.LineItem(item)
    console.dir(@collection)
    @render()
```

I even begin to send only some specific attributes instead of whole attributes to avoid model ID duplication https://github.com/dirty-hippie/chocolate/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/views/ingredient.js.coffee#L31

Here is working code, but all labels are in russian http://enigmatic-ridge-6116.herokuapp.com/constructor

Any help appricated!

Answer (score 0):

You defaults on your lineitems are not primitives.  Try making defaults a function that returns {ingredients: [], form: null }